# Create multiple facades for same product?

Tags: theme-development, e-commerce

Consider you sell zucchinis (courgette for those British, French).

And that is exactly my problem.

If I make a product called Zucchini - then it'll list on Google as Zucchini. But then I will not get customers who search Courgette.

I could make 2 listings, with different titles but otherwise identical. That solves the problem quite well but it seems stupid to duplicate the listing just for a name - and it makes inventory management a headache. Some products I sell have 10 unique "names" that people could search for - so it's not nice to have such a long title:

> zucchinis/ courgette/ Baby marrow/ marrow/ green gourd/ summer squash

Is there some way to create a base "Zucchini" page and then a facade page that inherits all of it but changes the title to be Courgette?